# Using bytes in swift3

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

```
float *vertexBuffer = (float *)positionSource.data.bytes;
```

> 'bytes' is unavailable: use withUnsafeBytes instead

but I don't know how to use it

```
_ = positionSource?.data.withUnsafeBytes({ (<#UnsafePointer<ContentType>#>) -> ResultType in

   })
```

Comment: Which type is `positionSource` and what's its content?

Comment: `let positionSource = sphereNode.geometry?.getGeometrySources(for: .vertex)[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withUnsafeBytes` is a generic method, the `ContentType` is inferred
from the type of the closure. With

```
data.withUnsafeBytes { (vertexBuffer: UnsafePointer<Float>) in
    // Use  vertexBuffer ...
}
```

you'll get a `UnsafePointer<Float>` pointing to the bytes in the data.
Note that this pointer must not be used outside of the closure.

You can also compute a result and pass it back from the closure
to the caller. Example:

```
let result = data.withUnsafeBytes { (vertexBuffer: UnsafePointer<Float>) -> Float in
    let result = // ... compute result ...
    return result
}
```

Comment: How to do if I want to use vertexBuffer outside of the closure? I want to keep the code clean.

Comment: @JohnAstion: `Data` provides access to its bytes only within a closure environment. What is your "cleanliness" concern?

Comment: Get it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this.

```
let str = "hello"
let strData = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
strData.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<CChar>) -> Void in
          print("\(bytes[1])")  //exp: access as c string
}
```

Hope to help you!